# Ignore invalid scopes while generating token

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

We are in the process of upgrading our keycloak setup from 6.0.1 to 11.0.0 and it seems like from Keycloak 10 onward the token generation complains with error "invalid scope" if the scope parameter is invalid.

Intially we were using Keycloak 3 with RBAC (user and roles assigned to them) and full scoped clients (only Direct Access Grants Enabled = true) this used to worked fine where we were passing required roles in scope and used to get access token for request roles (in scope) and later we updated it to Keycloak 6 which used to work fine with this setup as well, however updating it to Keycloak 11 breaks it since we do not use fine grained scopes so passing existing roles to scope sort of broke it, however if I do not provide any scope then it works fine.

My setup looks like below

Roles:

- Role1
- Role2
- Role3

Users:

- User1
- User2

User-Role Mapping

- Role1, Role2 --> User1
- ROle3 --> User2

Clients

- Client1
  AccessType: Cofidential
  Direct Access Grants: Enabled
  Scoped: Full Scoped

Generated token

```
{
  "exp": 1598869296,
  "iat": 1598867496,
  "jti": "b5cd4395-1ba2-471b-9e3f-86fa7c699d72",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8480/auth/realms/EDP",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "2efa51cd-1afb-4f18-83c4-12e4017739b5",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "service",
  "session_state": "a4925385-b787-4ae7-a076-a4b92b5df87c",
  "acr": "1",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "Rol1",
      "offline_access",
      "uma_authorization",
      "Rol2"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "default roles",
  "unique_name": "User1",
  "preferred_username": "User1",
  "tid": "Foo"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the token generation complains with error "invalid scope" if the scope parameter is invalid"? Which component complains? Which scope parameter are you talking about? Can you provide an example? Could you please provide more information about your components, clients and configuration to try and estimate the impact? Note that OAuth2 scopes are not an option that can be bypassed easily but their usage can be strongly limited (as specs are not really enforcing on scopes). I won't pretend to answer your question but surely without more information no one will.

Comment: @bsaverino apologies for late reply, I've updated question

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Three questions so far: (1) what if you specify "openid", "your-client-id" and eventually one of your roles in the scopes parameter when requesting a token? (will it work?). (2) What do you get as a response from the token endpoint? (which error? and any keycloak log?). (3)  When not specifying scopes - you say it works - what does the retrieved token look like? (can you show its content?)

Comment: @bsaverino I did not get your point #1 but for #3 I get the correct response, updated the question with same